# Javascript array sent to php and back with ajax returns null

Tags: ajax, json, decode, encode, stringify

I have a bit of a problem with using ajax to hand over a js array to php.
When i echo it back, it always returns "null".

js part (answers is a one dimentional array containing ints):

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(answers);

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./secure/db_write.php",
            data: {userAction:"insertAnswers", userAnswers:jsonString},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

php part (abstract):

```
$var_userAction = @$_POST['userAction'];
$var_userAnswers = json_decode($_POST['userAnswers']);

if(isset($var_userAction)){     
    if($var_userAction == "insertAnswers"){
        insertAnswers($var_userAnswers);
    }
}

function insertAnswers($userAnswers){
    echo json_encode($userAnswers);
};
```

It works with single variables, but i cant get an array to be passed and returned correctly.

Am i missing something?

edit:

array[1,2,3,4]

where every number can be betweeen 1 and 4.

alerting the array prompts 1,2,3,4
alerting the stringified array prompts ["1","2","3","4"]

Comment: Lets see the array you're sending.

Comment: ok, finally found it. the numbers in the array where all strings. they were taken from checkbox values. converted them to ints and everything works flawless!